# Visual Studio 2013 Schema Compare/Publish ignores column order in definition of foreign key constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2013, database-schema, database-project

Visual Studio schema compare and database publishing tools are not detecting differences in the order of the columns defining foreign keys.

Assume the following foreign key constraint exists on Source Database/Database Project:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.ReferencingTable
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_1
FOREIGN KEY (Column1, Column2)
REFERENCES dbo.ReferencedTable (Column1, Column2)
```

Assume Target Database/Database Project to be exactly the same except that for foreign key FK_1, columns are defined in a different order (Notice the Column2 now pointing to dbo.ReferencedTable.Column1, and Column 1 is pointing to dbo.ReferencedTable.Column2) like this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.ReferencingTable
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_1
FOREIGN KEY (Column2, Column1)
REFERENCES dbo.ReferencedTable (Column1, Column2)
```

Note: Assume columns are type compatible (Ex. all INT)

I would expect VS to detect this difference and generate the proper script to update the target schema (namely the target foreign key).

Could not find a Setting/Option to control this behavior. Is this a bug?

Comment: There used to be an "Ignore column order" option but it was removed in VS 2012/2013. This option applied to the column order in table definitions but I'm not sure if it also applied to foreign key constraints.

Comment: Keith, thanks for replying. Yes, I'm aware of such option. It applied to column order in tables and helped avoid table rebuilds. In my opinion, that option made sense. However, thinking about it, I don't see how an option to enable/disable this behavior for keys would even make sense in the first place. Keys (and their column mappings implied by column order) have to be interpreted as defined, this is not an option. Disabling this behavior would violate relational principles.

Comment: I just tried to switch the order of an FK relationship's columns in SSDT 2012. It wouldn't let me change the order and build successfully if the columns didn't line up with the PK order in the parent table. So Column1,Column2 would only work if that were the order of the PK's columns in the parent table.

Comment: Peter, thanks for trying that out. However, notice that column names are irrelevant as long as they are type compatible. If Column1 and Column2 were of the same type (say INT), it would definitely let you define the FK however you want.

Comment: Got it - just did a test w/ SSDT 2012 and got the same behavior. Sounds like a bug to me as that makes a rather huge difference when pushing code if you got that wrong the first time. Possible to fix in post-deploy, but ugly and you need to know that there's a problem.

Comment: It seems to be a bug. Another workaround is just renaming the constraint. That's what I did to get VS to "detect the change".

Comment: Good to know. Horrible that you have to rename, but at least it's an option. I would caution trying to do that in SQL 2005, especially if the constraint was "system named" because there's a bug in 2005 that doesn't clear out the "system named" flag on a rename for some reason.

Comment: I have added this issue to Microsoft Connect: [visual-studio-2013-sql-server-data-tools-schema-compare-publish-ignores-column-order-in-definition-of-foreign-key-constraint](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/911781/visual-studio-2013-sql-server-data-tools-schema-compare-publish-ignores-column-order-in-definition-of-foreign-key-constraint)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the issue is a bug with SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT). Microsoft will include the fix in their next SSDT refresh on VS2012, VS2013, and the RTM of the next Visual Studio version. See link for more information:

[Visual Studio 2013/SQL Server Data Tools: Schema Compare/Publish ignores column order in definition of foreign key constraint](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/911781/visual-studio-2013-sql-server-data-tools-schema-compare-publish-ignores-column-order-in-definition-of-foreign-key-constraint)

Comment: I have confirmed this bug is fixed on SSDT 12.0.50318.0